# Evitar salto de linea de etiqueta <p> </p>

Tags: html, css

Con las propiedades css estoy obteniendo lo que es un contador de página, el cual lo coloco en la etiqueta de párrafo en html, el problema surge que la propiedad por defecto hace un salto de línea el cual deforma el contenido de mi html, pues también tengo incrustado php de la siguiente manera:

```
<style>
footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0cm;
        left: 0cm;
        right: 0cm;
        height: 2cm;
    }
    #page::after{
        /* display:inline; */
       float: inline-start;
        content: counter(page);
        font-style: bold
    }
</style>


<body>
<footer>
<div class="firmas">
            <p>
                <?php echo $nombredoc; ?></b> de fecha <?php echo fechaEs($periodo_ini) . ", "; ?>
                instrumento que consta de <p id='page'></p> fojas útiles tamaño carta, escrito solo en el anverso, incluida la presente.
            </p>
        </div>
</footer>
</body>
```

Como lo mencioné esto lo que provoca es un salto de línea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les agradecería mucho su ayuda. gracias de antemano

Comment: Lo mas útil es que uses <span>, solucionas ese error sin tener que usar css

Answer (score 4):

Una solución podría ser redefinir el estilo de las etiquetas **p** (suponiendo que lo quieras para todas), de forma que sean inline

```
p{          
    display: inline;
}
```

Pero vería más lógico usar la etiqueta **span** en este caso, en lugar de **p**

Comment: Exacto, no tiene sentido usar las etiquetas de Párrafo, para otra cosa que no sean Párrafos.

Answer (score 1):

Cada elemento tiene unas propiedades por así decirla "predeterminadas" y la etiqueta **p** viene con salto de linea ( en bloque ) como también viene por ejemplo la etiqueta **div**, así que debes cambiarlo con **display**

```css
p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>Esto es un parrado p sin salto de linea</p>
<p>porque lo hemos puesto inline</p>
```